# Cannot change credit card for a failed payment

Tags: store, microsoft-account

I canceled one of my credit cards that were associated with my Microsoft Account as a backup payment card. There is one other credit card and a PayPal account also associated with the account.

For some reason one—and just one out of a dozen—purchases in the Windows Phone Marketplace was charged to this canceled credit card. Now I am stuck with a problem that I cannot seem to resolve:

The [Microsoft Account billing web site](https://commerce.microsoft.com) allows me to add new payment methods, but not to change the payment method for a failed payment. I cannot remove the old credit card either because it has a outstanding payment

Of course, Microsoft does not offer support for Microsoft Accounts and billing in my home country of Norway. So I have no way of contacting them about the issue.

I got a menacing email saying my account would be closed for further purchases if I did not resolve this issue quickly.

What the *beep* am I supposed to do?

I have never had this much trouble for a 7 NOK app on iOS nor Android before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had reasonable success [chatting with Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/contactus/#chat) about my account billing issue. They probably cannot directly solve your problem, but they might be able to point you in the right direction. Or you could try calling [support](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/customer-service-phone-numbers/en-gb#n) on +47 23 500 500.

[image: MS Chat]

*I know you said *Microsoft does not offer support for Microsoft Accounts*, but please try the above if you haven't already. Posting this as a general purpose answer for any related questions.

Comment: After being passed around a bit and having talked a bit what felt like half the support department: they finally found someone who could resolve my issue. Total time on the phone: 48 minutes.