# Wrong language in marketplace after update to 7.8

Tags: store, htc, 7.8, nokia-lumia-800, language-setting

After the **update to 7.8**, all descriptions of apps and games in the **marketplace** are in **italian** instead of english as before.

I've experienced this on both my HTC Trophy and Nokia Lumia 800. It therefore doesn't seem to be a model specific problem.

No other aspect of the phone is affected by this problem. After I install an app, it appears in english (english title in the menu).

Since there is no setting for the marketplace language, I suppose they messed something up when making available the marketplace to more countries.

The *Display language* as well as the *Browser & search language* are set to *English (United States)*.

Though italian is one of the official languages in Switzerland, I'd really prefer to have access to the marketplace in english, german or french.

**How can I change the marketplace language?**

Comment: If it's happening on more than one phone, perhaps there's a language setting in your Microsoft Account that got changed?

Comment: @MichaelItzoe Which setting could that be? I couldn't find anything on xbox or windowsphone.com ...

Comment: The language is tied to your MS account and I don't think it can be changed by you (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2692008). I would suggest contacting support and see what options they can give you http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/1257/295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple people have reported the same issue here: http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-7/177931-marketplace-wrong-language.html

If it was a mistake in the update, there is probably nothing you can do to fix it until a new update comes out.

Comment: Either the lastest update ([7.10.8862.144](http://wp7roottools.com/index.php/developer-blog/106-update-8860-does-not-fix-live-tiles)) fixed this, or as somebody mentioned in the link you provided, they fixed it on their server since people having the same problem have seen this issue corrected without installing the update.