# How necessary is the 7.8 update?

Tags: 7.8

I'm eagerly awaiting the 7.8 update (although realistically I expect to upgrade to a WP8 device before 7.8 is even available from my carrier), but my wife has expressed distaste for the larger tiles based on what she's seen in commercials. Since I'm her "IT pro" I always make sure here phone and laptop are up-to-date with the latest security and stability enhancements.

To my knowledge 7.8 brings the updated start screen and little else. Since she's not due to upgrade for another year, my question is would she be missing anything important (again, such as security or stability fixes) by not upgrading to 7.8?

Comment: I think you question might be better if it was worded "What new features and fixes does 7.8 bring?" As it stands 'how necessary' can't really deliver a concrete answer.

Comment: I should have added she has an LG Quantum. She also likes the margin on the right of the start screen, so while she understands tiles can be resized, she doesn't like the layout. And by "necessary" I was stressing security and stability fixes. It doesn't appear 7.8 has many if at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The update doesn't bring [much](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/start/whats-new-in-windows-phone):

- Resizeable live tiles
- You now have 20 accent colours
- The lock screen can show the Bing image of the day

Nokia have updated some of their [applications/features](http://conversations.nokia.com/2013/01/30/get-even-more-from-your-nokia-lumia-with-windows-phone-7-8/) for 7.8

> As well as major system updates, there has been a stream of exciting
>   new features introduced to Nokia Lumia. These include Internet
>   sharing, Bluetooth sharing, imaging enhancements like Camera Extras,
>   and the release of apps such as Contact Share, Play To and Nokia City
>   Lens that are available.

Comment: Since she doesn't have a Nokia, the update offers nothing of interest to her. But this is what I was looking for.

Comment: There may be bug fixes, but I have not seen any updates around that. If her device is working fine, then I guess you don't need to worry about fixes.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the phone, it could contain other fixes. And she doesn't have to re-size the tiles to bigger or smaller ones, she can make them whatever size she wants.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with the 7.8 update regarding live tile updates; some live tiles appear to update several times a minute, using excessive data and reducing battery life.

http://www.wp7roottools.com/index.php/developer-blog/105-bad-live-tiles-the-saga-continues

I've found the Bing translate live tile with the word of the day suffers from this issue, so it is a case of removing the tile until this issue has been resolved.
Otherwise, the ability to resize tiles is great, you can fit more on one screen.

Comment: It's not clear from your answer whether you were seeing these issues on 7.5 (and prior), or if this is specific to updating to 7.8?

Comment: This affects 7.8

Answer (score 0):

[In some cases (probably related to the country/marketplace)](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1541/243), it may even break something.

Otherwise +1 to row1 for new Nokia applications such as Bluetooth sharing.

Comment: This has been fixed since.

Answer (score 0):

If you want resizable tiles then go for it, problem with big tiles is that you don't have many apps on the screen, the max is 8. So if tiles are smaller then you can add more shortcuts.